# Proof checking of a question regarding characteristic polynomial of a $n×n$ real matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $p(x) = a_0 + a_1x +...+ a_nx^n$ be the characteristic polynomial of a $n×n$ matrix $A$ with real entries. Which of the following statements are true?

(A) $p(x)$ has no repeated roots.

(B) $p(x)$ can be expressed as a product of linear polynomials with real co-efficients.

(C) If $p(x)$ can be expressed as a product of linear polynomials with real co-efficients then there is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ consisting of eigen vectors of $A$.

**My attempt :**

(A) If $p(x) = {(x-a)}^n$ then this statement is false. Such matrix exists e.g $I_{n×n}$.

(B) If $p(x) = 0$ has at least a complex root the there will be a factor whose co-efficients will be complex. Therefore this also false.

(C) According to the statement In this case $p(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n (a_ix+b_i)$. This means there are n distinct eigen values, resulting in n L.I eigen vectors which will generate $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Are all my reasonings true? The given answer is the option (C). I'm a bit confused about the language given in option B and C. Are my implications from those options true?

Comment: Be careful in C: do the eigenvalues **have** to be different?

Comment: @paulinho I was exactly thinking about it. But does the language in C mean what I thought of? Otherwise C also isn't true.

Comment: I don't think the language in (C) is implying that the eigenvalues are distinct, so as you say C is false also

Comment: @NoahSolomon I think so too. Thanks.